# spltter EIP not working with simple statement

Tags: split, apache-camel

I don't know if it is me or this is a bug. but, I've tried several iterations of using ${body.skip(1)} with the split EIP and it doesn't work. it continues to throw exception Invalid content was found starting with element 'simple'. One of ...

test xml code

```
    <route 
        id="core.predix.consumer.route"
        autoStartup="true" >
        <from id="predixConsumer" ref="predixConsumer" />   
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />

    <split streaming="true" strategyRef="TSAggregationStrategy"> <!-- stopOnException="true" streaming="true" > -->
    <simple>${body.skip(1)}</simple>
    <tokenize token="\n"/>

    <log message="Split line ${body}"/>         
    </split>
    <log message="after split body: ${body}" />
    <to uri="{{fileDestinationEndpoint}}" />
</route>
```

throws
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'simple'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":onException, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":when, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint":onCompletion,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have both

```
<simple>${body.skip(1)}</simple>
<tokenize token="\n"/>
```

As the splitter expression, if you want to skip the first line then you can use the `skipFirst` option the tokenizer

```
<tokenize token="\n" skipFirst="true"/>
```

Comment: I figured that the way of trial and error. thank you once again Claus. we should just pipe in to your head :) books, web, searching, .... end up dead ends. thank you ! I have put a filter in the processor that seems to work ok. if ( (Integer.valueOf((int)exchange.getProperty("CamelSplitIndex"))) > 0 ) {

Answer (score 0):

thank you Claus, I will give that a try. I have a solution that did work I'd like to share also. again thank you. test code below. the exchange getProperty CamelSplitIndex works as expected here.

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception, 
TimeStampCannotBeParsedException {

    log.info("Entering TimeStamp Enrichment Processor...");

    String rec = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String[] sa = rec.split(",");
    log.info("TimeStamp to be enriched: " + sa[0]);

    if ( (Integer.valueOf((int)exchange.getProperty("CamelSplitIndex"))) > 0 ) {

        DateUtil fromPattern = new DateUtil();
        final String patternOfDateToConvert = fromPattern.dateFormatPattern(sa[0].trim());
        log.info("Pattern Of Date to Convert: " + patternOfDateToConvert );         
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(patternOfDateToConvert).parse(sa[0].trim());
            final String todate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").format(date);
            log.info("Converted Date: " + todate);
            sa[0] = todate;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new TimeStampCannotBeParsedException("Timestamp Cannot be Converted to Date. Invalid Format!");
        }

        String str = Arrays.toString(sa);
        String record = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
        log.info("New Record: " + record);
        rec = record + "\r\n";
    } else {
        rec = rec + "\r\n";
    }
    log.info("out Body: " + rec);
    exchange.getIn().setBody(rec);
    log.info("Leaving TimeStamp Enrichment Processor...");

}
```